# Setting up a development environment with Iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, iptables-redirect

I am trying to set up a development environment and all my applications are divided in two parts. The ReactJS front-end is accessed at `http://127.0.0.1:3000` and the Ruby back-end is at `http://127.0.0.1:3001`.

I added these two lines to my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.2     myapp.dev
127.0.0.3     api.myapp.dev
```

This way, when I make a browser request like `http://myapp.dev`, I need it to be redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`. And when my front-end make an AJAX call to the API using `http://api.myapp.dev`, I need this request redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:3001`.

I need to route all requests from `127.0.0.2` to `127.0.0.1:3000` and all requests from `127.0.0.3` to `127.0.0.2:3001`.

I know this could be done setting up a reverse proxy. But for many reasons I'd like to know if it is possible to do this with IPTABLES. And if so, how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The statement "I need to route all requests from 127.0.0.2 to 127.0.0.1:3000" doesn't necessarily make sense, because while the second address includes a port the first does not.  You want to reroute *any* connection, regardless of port, from 127.0.0.2 to 127.0.0.1:3000? Or you want to reroute, for example, traffic from http://127.0.0.2 (which would default to port 80) to http://127.0.0.1:3000?

Comment: This second option sounds good to me, i.e., reroute traffic from `127.0.0.2:80` to `127.0.0.1:3000`, @larsks.

Comment: Assuming that browser requests default to port 80, this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect access to from `127.0.0.2:80` to `127.0.0.1:3000`, you could do something like:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 127.0.0.2 \
  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.2 \
  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

The first rule (in the `PREROUTING` chain) will match traffic originating from somewhere other than your local host.  The second rule (in the `OUTPUT` chain) will match traffic originating from your local host.

Note that rules in an iptables chain are processed *in order*, so if there are existing rules in your firewall that match before these rules, the results may not be what you expect.

For details, read about the `REDIRECT` target in the [iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) man page.

Comment: One question: I noticed you never mention, in both rules, the `127.0.0.1` IP, just the port 3000. Isn't this necessary?

Comment: Did you read the section of the man page about the `REDIRECT` target? It "It redirects the packet to the machine itself by changing the destination IP to the primary address of the incoming interface", which for anything listening on `lo` will be `127.0.0.1`.